# Trouble understanding with getting a unique instantiation in Python

Tags: python, class, instantiation

I have an employee class which has an **init** method that reads an employees record in from a file. I also have an employees class which has an *init*_ method that attempts to read in all of the employee records.

I am having trouble with **init** for the employees class. Here is my code:

```
class EmployeeList():
      records=[]
      def __init__(self):
          with open(database) as fp:
              emp=employee(fp)
              while (emp.id > 0):
                    print(emp)
                    self.records.append(emp)
                    emp=employee(fp)
```

The print(emp) is there for error checking, it shows that the records are being read in properly. When the EOF is reached, the **init** method for the employee sets the id to 0 and the name of the employee to "". I have two problems:

1. After the loop, all of the employees in employees.records are the same - id 0 and blanks for names. I am assuming that that emp is not creating a new instance each time it is called, and so all of the employees are being set to that one instance of emp, the very last one from when EOF is reached.
2. I doubt my code is "Pythonesque"; suggestions for improvement are welcome.

P.S. database is globally defined to the file name.

The entire code is here, sorry about the length:

```
class employee:
    count = 0
    def __init__(self,f=None):
        if (f==None): # a user is inputting the employee
           self.lastname = input("Employees last name:")
           while type(self.lastname)!=type("1"):
                 print("Your input needs to be a name\n")
                 self.lastname = input("Employees last name:")
           self.firstname = input("Employees first name:")
           while type(self.firstname)!=type("1"):
                  print("Your input needs to be a name\n")
                  self.firstname = input("Employees first name:")
           self.payrate = float(input("Employees pay rate:"))
           while type(self.payrate)!=type(0.0):
                  print("Your input needs to be a pay rate\n")
                  self.payrate = float(input("Employees pay rate:"))
           employee.count = employee.count + 1
           self.id = employee.count
        else: # the employee is being read in from the database and f is a file pointer
              # read in an employee record and return false for end of file.
           checkEOF = f.readline().rstrip('\r\n') #check for end of file
           if (checkEOF != ""):
               employee.id = int(checkEOF)
               employee.firstname = f.readline().rstrip('\r\n')
               employee.lastname = f.readline().rstrip('\r\n')
               employee.payrate = float(f.readline().rstrip('\r\n'))
           else:
               employee.id = 0
               employee.firstname = " "
               employee.lastname = " "
               employee.payrate = 0.0
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.id)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.id == other.id
        return NotImplemented
    def __str__(self):
        return "Employee " + str(self.id) + " is "+self.firstname + " "+self.lastname+" and their pay rate is "+str(self.payrate)+"\n"
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if (self.lastname < other.lastname):
           return True
        elif (self.lastname > other.lastname):
           return False
        else: #same last names
           if (self.firstname < other.firstname):
              return True
           elif (self.firstname > other.firstname):
              return False
           else: #same names
             if (self.id < other.id):
                return True
             else: # note that ids cannot be the same
                return False
    def __gt__(self, other):
        if (self.lastname > other.lastname):
           return True
        elif (self.lastname < other.lastname):
           return False
        else: # Same last names
           if (self.firstname > other.firstname):
              return True
           elif (self.firstname > other.firstname):
              return False
           else: # Same names
             if (self.id > other.id):
                return True
             else: # note that ids cannot be the same
                return False
    def payraise(self,payraise):
        self.payrate = self.payrate+payraise
    def saveemployee(self,fp):
        fp.write(str(self.id)+"\n")
        fp.write(self.firstname+"\n")
        fp.write(self.lastname+"\n")
        fp.write(str(self.payrate)+"\n")

class EmployeeList():
    records=[]
    def __init__(self):
        with open(database) as fp:
             emp=employee(fp)
             while (emp.id > 0):
                   print(emp)
                   self.records.append(emp)
                   emp=employee(fp)
    def __str__(self):
        employeesprint = ""
        for emp in self.records:
            employeesprint = employeesprint + str(emp)
        return employeesprint
    def save(self):
        self.records.sort()
        with open(database,"w+") as fp:
             fp.seek(0)
             for emp in self.records:
                   emp.saveemployee(fp)
def menu():
    print("\n")
    print(choices[0]+". Add another employee")
    print(choices[1]+". Print employees")
    print(choices[len(choices)-1]+". Quit")
    print("\n")

employees = EmployeeList()
choices = ["A","B","C"]
ch = "N"
while (ch != choices[len(choices)-1]):
    menu()
    ch=input("Make your choice ")
    while not (ch in choices):
        menu()
        ch=input("Make your choice ")
    if (ch == choices[0]):
        employees.records.append(employee())
        employees.save()
    if (ch == choices[1]):
        print(employees)
```

Sample output: You can see the two employees correctly being printed as they are read in:

Employee 1 is jane bob and their pay rate is 1.0

Employee 2 is jim bob and their pay rate is 3.4

A. Add another employee

B. Print employees

C. Quit

Make your choice B

Employee 0 is     and their pay rate is 0.0

Employee 0 is     and their pay rate is 0.0

Comment: So let's see the Employee class `__init__` code...

Comment: To make code more "Pythonesque" use spaces around `=` - `records = []` , `emp = employee(fp)`. See [Whitespace in Expressions and Statements](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements) in PEP8

Comment: Post the code or we can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code:

```
       if (checkEOF != ""):
           employee.id = int(checkEOF)
           employee.firstname = f.readline().rstrip('\r\n')
           employee.lastname = f.readline().rstrip('\r\n')
           employee.payrate = float(f.readline().rstrip('\r\n'))
       else:
           employee.id = 0
           employee.firstname = " "
           employee.lastname = " "
           employee.payrate = 0.0
```

change 'employee' to 'self', 'employee' is the name of the class.

Comment: Oh good grief. I thought it might be something dumb, but that was bad. Cannot tell you how many times I looked at that code and did not see that. Thanks!!!!

Comment: @user3353877 this is a good reason to capitalize class names and lower_case instance names, if you were looking for one :)